# Mock httpBackend request globally

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In AngularJs unittest (Jasmine/Karma), we need to put `httpBackend.whenGET('/.*/').respond('')`
and some other default responds in the global beforeEach().

However, we get `Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!` because we will also need to mock other services / import other modules in the actual tests.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please, show your tests. The problem is not httpBackend but `module` that appears after `inject`.

Comment: @estus, you're right. I guess it's a design problem. But also curious why can't I inject before module importing?

Comment: `module` defines modules that are loaded in current test run. The first `inject` call bootstraps the app and creates the injector from currently loaded modules. It is not obvious from the docs, but under Angular's hood it is like that.